# Riotjs (Riot typescript) can't overwrite method on typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript, riot.js, riotts

This is weird. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Store extends Riot.Observable {
  trigger():void {
   // shouldn't this be completely overwriting the trigger method on riot.observable? 
   console.log("my trigger....");
  }
}

let store = new Store();
store.trigger();
```

Expected behaviour: "my trigger...." in the console. What I get is the original implementation of trigger on the Riot.Observable, which errors because of no parameters being passed.

If I poke the `store` object I can see on `store.__proto__` does have trigger on there, with my implementation. But `store` iself has its own (original) copy of `trigger()`

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/5spbvpnn/

I referenced [this with a very basic example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09%2F%2F%20A%20protected%20method%0A%09protected%20doStuff()%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09alert(%22Called%20from%20A%22)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20Expose%20the%20protected%20method%0A%09public%20callDoStuff()%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09this.doStuff()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%7B%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20Override%20the%20protected%20method%0A%09protected%20doStuff()%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20If%20we%20want%20we%20can%20still%20explicitely%20call%20the%20initial%20method%0A%09%09super.doStuff()%3B%0A%09%09alert(%22Called%20from%20B%22)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Aa.callDoStuff()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Will%20only%20alert%20%22Called%20form%20A%22%0A%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%0Ab.callDoStuff()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Will%20alert%20%22Called%20form%20A%22%20then%20%22Called%20from%20B%22), and I don't know what's going on.

Comment: That means riot observables don't use prototypes, but functions as members. regular inheritance will not help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/nippur72/RiotTS/blob/master/riot-ts.js), riot observables do not take advantage of prototypical inheritance. They work as mixins instead. The typescript wrapper class just calls the original riot mixin. To overwrite a function, you have to assign it to the instance:

```
class Store extends Riot.Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.trigger = function() {
            console.log("My trigger");
        };
    }
}

let store = new Store();
store.trigger();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.